# React update warning when using window event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I leave a route component, I get the following warning:

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op.

The warning started appearing after I added the scroll event listener. How do I prevent this warning? I'm binding the event method only once. The event listener is added in componentDidMount and removed in componentWillUnmount.

```
class DashboardRoute extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            scrolled: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(this.handleScroll, 250));
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', throttle(this.handleScroll, 250));
    }

    handleScroll (e) {
        let scrolled = (window.scrollY > 0);
        if (scrolled !== this.state.scrolled) {
            this.setState({scrolled: scrolled});
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <!-- Component code -->
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear about the warning? Which part do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the scroll event handler can be delayed as much as 250 ms, your component might be unmounted before it is called. This depends on how `DashboardRoute` is used throughout your app.

You can use an instance variable called e.g. `_mounted` that keep track of if the component is actually still mounted or not and use that in your scroll handler before you use `setState`.

`window.removeEventListener('scroll', throttle(this.handleScroll, 250))` will also try to remove a newly created function as scroll listener, so the listener created in `window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(this.handleScroll, 250))` will not be removed. You can create the throttled method once instead and reference that.

**Example**

```
class DashboardRoute extends React.Component {
  _mounted = true;
  state = {
    scrolled: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._mounted = false;
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = throttle(e => {
    let scrolled = window.scrollY > 0;
    if (this._mounted && scrolled !== this.state.scrolled) {
      this.setState({ scrolled: scrolled });
    }
  }, 250);

  render() {
    return <div>{/* ... */}</div>;
  }
}
```